User Defined Functions (UDFs) on update in ClickHouse
I created a user defined function in ClickHouse (version 23.12.2.59) and I can use it in my queries, it works fine, but I cannot use it in updating a column.
Is there a config I am missing? Shouldn't it work for update too?
Here is how I use it in my update query:
ALTER TABLE table1 UPDATE column2 = func1(column1) WHERE 1;

And here is what I get:
Code: 46. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Unknown function func1: While processing func1(column1). (UNKNOWN_FUNCTION)


What version of ClickHouse are you using?

version 23.12.2.59

try to upgrade to 24.3 clickhouse-server version

Update your clickhouse version to the newer major version 24. It was a bug which is resolved now.
